# Typesetting option that includes makeindex (TeX Live, TeXworks)

Tags: pdftex, texlive, texworks

I used to work with the MiKTeX distribution and the included TeXworks program. The latter provided me with a typesetting-configuration that was something like `pdfLaTeX + BibTeX + MakeIndex`. (It created the index files automatically.)

Now that I changed to TeX Live (still working with TeXworks which comes now with TeX Live, though) such an option is no longer available. I'd have to run `MakeIndex` and `pdfLaTeX` (two compilations) seperately.

I don't know the syntax for building my own typesetting-configuration which would provide me with the mentioned features (`pdfLaTeX` and `MakeIndex` in particular).
Could someone show me how to build that setting, please? Or post the settings of the said MikTeX typesetting configuration.

Comment: I wonder---does TeXworks support custom build scripts? Given that it's a TUG release, I'd imagine so, but I've never used it.

Comment: Assuming you have [latest TeXworks](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/downloads/list?can=2&q=) depending on OS. Does [Defining new typesetting tools](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#Introduction) help you and more advanced Qt [ScriptingTeXworks](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/ScriptingTeXworks)  As usual the [latest manual](https://texworks.googlecode.com/files/TeXworks-manual-r1029.pdf) is composed of all hints to use editor efficiently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pdfLaTeX + Makeindex + BibTeX` option in MiKTeX TeXWorks calls a MiKTeX-only command-line tool called `texify` ([manual](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html) [pages](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texifying.html)). There are several tools that do (nearly) the same thing, such as [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk), [`rubber`](https://launchpad.net/rubber/) and [`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara). Choose one, learn the command line options from its manual, and then in TexWorks, under Edit/Preferences/Typesetting, add the program to "Processing Tools".

Note that `latexmk` is a Perl script so it needs a Perl interpreter to run; Rubber is written in Python so you need Python installed if there is no pre-compiled exe(cutable). Arara has pre-packaged installer for Windows.

Regarding options, you will surely have to add `$fullname`, which is the TeXWorks way of substituting the filename, and something like `-pdf` to generate PDF instead of DVI.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at one of these tools! I would like to "accept" the answer a little bit later; after I started working with the tools, to be exact, in case I'd like to add something here. :)

Is there one of the listed tools you prefer?

Comment: @LCsa No, I'm still using MiKTeX and `texify`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something as follows (Edit > Preferences > Typesetting > +):

[image: Creating custom compilation options]

Depending on the location of your installation, your .bat file would be something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" %1 %2 %3
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\bibtex.exe" %4
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\makeindex.exe" %4
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" %1 %2 %3
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" %1 %2 %3
```

Comment: What do the `%1` through `%4` mean? Are they the elements of the argument list? What is `%4` then?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit->Preference menu and select the Typesetting. In the Processing tools section click on "+" to add your processing chain as shown in the dialog box below and save
[image: Dialog box]

Comment: As marczellm pointed out already, `texify` is a MiKteX-only feature -- I work with TeX Live, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use this guide to for latexmk
https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latexmk

Comment: Link-only answers are not satisfactory. Moreover, the use of [`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) is already suggested in [marczellm's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127424/5764).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Mac OS X TexWorks setup for latexmk to run pdflatex]

See the snapshot of the setup on Mac OS X of Texworks running latexmk -pdf option